# How to show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |(\sin x/x)^n|<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How to show the following?$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\sin x}x\right|^n<\infty$$
I was wondering if there is a way to show that integral is finite by bounding $ |\frac{\sin x}{x}|^n$, where $n \geq 2$ is a positive integer, perhaps or if calculating the integral is the only conceivable way.

If the integral can be computed, should I be thinking along the lines of finding $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral)?

Appreciate a hint, thanks!

Comment: What is $n$? Positive integer? $n \geq 2$?

Comment: Sorry, yes $n\geq 2$ and is an integer.

Comment: Hint: $|\sin x|\leq 1$.

Comment: $(sinx/x)^n\rightarrow 0$ but not sure how that implies convergence. Can I say $\int (\frac{sinx}{x})^n< \int \frac{sinx}{x}<\infty$?

Comment: You probably want $|\sin x/x|^n$ in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|x|\geq 1$ you can bound the integral with $|sin(x)|\leq 1$ and then use the fact that $\int\limits_{|x|\geq 1} \frac 1{x^n} \mathrm{d}x \leq \int\limits_{|x|\geq 1} \frac 1{x^2} \mathrm{d}x = 2$.

For $|x|<1$ we use that $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$ such that the fraction is always smaller or equal to 1. Furthermore, we know that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$. Thus we are bounded by $\int\limits_{|x|\leq 1} \mathrm{d}x = 2$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\left| (\frac{\sin x}{x})^n \right| \leq \frac{1}{|x|^n} $$

**Hint 2** 
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{|x|^n} < \infty \\
\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{|x|^n} < \infty $$

**Hint 3:**$(\frac{\sin x}{x})^n$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$, thus Riemann integrable.